# IBM MobileFirst: Invoking adapter from Java- InvokeProcedure

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm trying to invoke a adapter from Java which is working fine with

```
DataAccessService service = WorklightBundles.getInstance().getDataAccessService();
ProcedureQName procedure = new ProcedureQName(adapterName,adapterProc);
service.invokeProcedure(procedure, String);
```

The issue comes in when the String in the above invokeProcedure has to be passed as an input to the invoked adapter. When there is no argument required it works, but when i pass a String(eg. "Hello") it breaks. The reason is, when it is invoked the value passed in the String argument is not parsed by the **Javascript adapter-impl.js.** and thus an error is thrown saying

> adapter name/procedurename cannot be invoked because of invalid
>   characters('H' line 1) in the String argument passed in runtime

I have tried to use the **JSONArray/JSONObject** in **com.ibm.json.java.*** package, but the error persists.

So tried using the other overload of `invokeProcedure(ProcedureQName,JSONArray,long nRequestID)`. Something like,

```
service.invokeProcedure(procedure, objArray,-1)
```

Surprisingly this is working fine for now. I wanted to understand whether,

1. is the right approach for this scenario and
2. will there be any issues in using the 3 argument overload of invokeProcedure in future ?

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass arguments as a stringified array. E.g.

```
service.invokeProcedure(procedure, "[1,2,3,4]");
service.invokeProcedure(procedure, "[1,2,'three','four']");
service.invokeProcedure(procedure, "[1,2,true,false]");
```

in case of a single argument just do an array with one single value

```
service.invokeProcedure(procedure, "['myStringParam']");
```

Another option is to create JSONArray object and stringify it.

Comment: Hi Anton, when I call invokeProcedure method it returned an error message [I O: Invalid token on line 1, column 14], do you have any idea about it?